# Why doesn't mount respect the ro option?

Tags: mount, ext4, readonly

I have a server where a partition (`/var`) switched to read-only. So I try to reproduce this problem on another server with the following command.

```
mount -o remount,ro /var/ -f
```

When I check our application log on that same partition I remounted ro I see entries recently added.

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/*
```

CentOS 6.7

Apache: 2.2.15

`uname -r`: `2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64`

Comment: which filesystem? Are you sure that /var/log is in the same partition as /var?  If you use mount without the `-f` flag, what error do you encounter?

Comment: I agree with @GiacomoCatenazzi.  `/var/log/` is occasionally given its own partition.  (check output of `df`).  If it is not a separate partition, I would try umounting, then doing a fresh mount to test whether remount is working.

Answer (score 15):

It is the correct behaviour.

You use the `-f` flag, which mean:

> `-f`, `--fake`:
>   Causes everything to be done except for the actual system call; if it's not obvious, this **``fakes''** mounting the filesystem.  This option is useful in conjunction with the `-v` flag to determine what the mount command is  trying to do.  It can also be used to add entries for devices that were mounted earlier with the `-n` option.  The `-f` option checks for an existing record in `/etc/mtab` and fails when the record already exists (with a regular non-
>                 fake mount, this check is done by the kernel).

See also [Remount a busy disk to read-only mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195010/remount-a-busy-disk-to-read-only-mode).

Comment: BTW I'm surprised that `-f` means *fake* and not *force*.

Comment: ... and that's why we have man pages

Comment: A bit confusingly, -f means *force* when used with the `umount` command.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GiacomoCatenazzi.  `/var/log/` is occasionally given its own partition.  (Check output of `df`).  If it is not a separate partition, I would try <del>umounting, then doing a fresh mount to test whether remount is working.</del>   editing the mount options in /etc/fstab then rebooting.  (only way to get a known fresh mount with /var).

Also, check results of `mount` (no options) (or cat /etc/mtab). `mount` with no options displays a version of /etc/mtab.  Look to see how /var (and possibly /var/log) are actually mounted.  /etc/mtab shows the actual parameters in use (including the defaults that were not overridden.)

Comment: Good luck unmounting `/var` on a running system.

Comment: Oh, there is that.

Comment: @jordanm Or rather, good luck having a running system after unmounting `/var`

Comment: You could even mount some other partition on /var, like if you wanted to modify the original partition to add space.  But it'd be easier to do offline using alternate boot media. You could even design the OS to not use /var at all, but it would be so different from the norm, the only person who could administer or troubleshoot it would be the person who built it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, the -f is probably why you're not seeing your changes on your test box.

However, that said.... in general linux will put partitions in read only mode when it encounters i/o errors. If the system who suddenly went read only is still up, you may wish to consider checking the logs for i/o errors. You may not be able to duplicate the issue on 'good' hardware. Check dmesg, as well as the system logs on the affected system. Odds are decent this is a degraded hardware issue you will need to address.

Comment: It will also be remounted read only if *you ask for it to be remounted read-only* like the asker is trying to do here.