# How to enforce fsck during booting system and before rootfs is mounted?

Tags: linux, mount, boot, fsck, e2fsck

I am working with embedded Linux build with Yocto. My goal is to enforce file checking during each system booting. So far I did the following steps:

1. I've modified the `/etc/default/rcS` file and I've set `ENABLE_ROOTFS_FSCK=yes` and `FSCKFIX=yes`.
2. I've used this command `tune2fs -c 1 <my_fs>` to check my fs during each booting.

I see the following log

```
`EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended`
```

before mounting the root partition, but fsck is trying to check the partition just after it was mounted. So the process is aborted. The log:

```
mount: / is busy
*** ERROR!  Cannot fsck root fs because it is not mounted read-only!
```

How can I enforce fsck to check the file system before mounting the partition? Thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remount a busy disk to read-only mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195010/remount-a-busy-disk-to-read-only-mode)

Comment: I think it doesn't answer my question. I would prefer to avoid unmounting the file system in use. I would like to run fsck before that file system become mounted.

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand your question, but:

There is no need to run `tune2fs` to run `fsck`. As you are not "tuning" any fs parameters, using `tune2fs` as a proxy for `fsck` simply adds overhead & may slow the boot process by a small amount.

Perhaps you meant `e2fsck`? `fsck` serves as a *"wrapper"* or *"front-end"* to provide *legacy* support. Typically, `fsck` simply calls `e2fsck` to do the real work.

Anyway - on to an answer:

I think `fsck` invocation can vary between OSs. One of my "embedded Linux" OS is RPi, and there are two methods for invoking `fsck` at boot time **before** the root filesystem is mounted:

1. create a file named `forcefsck` in the root of the filesystem `/`; i.e.

   ```bsh
   $ sudo touch /forcefsck
   ```

   This may have to be done before each boot - my OS deletes this file during boot
2. use your editor to add the following to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

   > fsck.mode=force

   ```
   $ nano /boot/cmdline.txt
   ```

   **FROM:**
   console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=6c586e13-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait

   **TO:**
   console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=6c586e13-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes rootwait

Again, I think this is OS-dependent, so YMMV.

Comment: $ sudo touch /forcefsck causes no effects. Parameter fsck.mode seems to be used by systemd, based on this link: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html but my Linux distro uses systemVinit.

Comment: @user1029384756: Sorry about that... figured to be a long shot, but thought it worth a try. I've nothing else to offer as I don't know Yocto. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

You need an initram file system to do that. Check the real root file system before you switch to the real root.

Once a file system is mounted, it can't (should not) be modified, and you can't unmount the root fs.

Comment: *Once a file system is mounted, it can't (should not) be modified, and you can't unmount the root fs.* - this is simply not true.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov which part? Should not be modified by fsck, or can't unmount while it is root? Yes, you can switch to another root and back, but it's more effort, and then it is not root while you check it.